# Este código debe devolverme la masa del aire del vehículo y el promedio de la masa de aire, pero devuelve valores en 0, ¿qué hago?

Tags: c++

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

class Taller {
  private:
    int c = 0, d = 0, x = 0, y = 0;
  float presion = 0, masa = 0, volumen = 0, temperatura = 0, sumaMoto = 0, sumaVehi = 0;

  public:
    void pedirDatos();
    float masaVehiculo(float, float, float);
    float masaMoto(float, float, float);
};

void Taller::pedirDatos() {
  cout << "¿Que masa desea calcular? Ingrese una de las opciones:  vehiculo = 1, moto = 2 " << endl;
  cin >> x;

  if (x = 1) {
    c = 0;
    c = c + 1;

    cout << "ingrese la presión del vehículo." << endl;
    cin >> presion;
    cout << "ingrese el volumen del vehículo." << endl;
    cin >> volumen;
    cout << "ingrese la temperatura del vehículo." << endl;
    cin >> temperatura;

    float solucion = masaVehiculo(presion, volumen, temperatura);

    cout << "la masa de aire del vehículo es:" << solucion << endl;

    float sumaVehi = 0;
    sumaVehi = sumaVehi + solucion;

    cout << "el promedio de masa de aire es:" << sumaVehi / c << endl;
  } else {
    d = 0;
    d = d + 1;

    cout << "ingrese la presión de la moto." << endl;
    cin >> presion;
    cout << "ingrese el volumen de la moto." << endl;
    cin >> volumen;
    cout << "ingrese la temperatura de la moto." << endl;
    cin >> temperatura;

    float solucion = masaMoto(presion, volumen, temperatura);

    cout << " la masa de aire de la moto es:" << solucion << endl;

    float sumaMoto = 0;
    sumaMoto = sumaMoto + solucion;
    cout << "el promedio de masa de aire de motos es:" << sumaMoto / d << endl;
  };

};

float Taller::masaVehiculo(float pre, float vol, float temp) {
  int masa;
  masa = (pre * vol) / (0, 37 * (temp + 460));
  return masa;
};

float Taller::masaMoto(float pre, float vol, float temp) {
  int masa;
  masa = (pre * vol) / (0, 37 * (temp + 460));
  return masa;
};

int main() {
    Taller obj1;
    obj1.pedirDatos();
```

Este código debe devolverme la masa del aire del vehículo y el promedio de la masa de aire, pero devuelve valores en 0 ¿Qué hago? Cuando compilo, no importa si oprimo 1 o 2, solo elije auto, y después los valores que me debe devolver los devuelve en 0: la masa del aire del vehículo y el promedio de la masa de aire.

Comment: El operador para comparar es `==` no `=`. `if ( x=1)` debería ser `if ( x==1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Solo elige vehículo porque en el método pedir datos no comparas con if(x==1)
Y retorna 0 ya que en los métodos tanto de masa vehículo, como masa moto, defines masa como un valor entero, y al hacer la operación esta masa es muy pequeña y como es entero, no va a mostrar los valores restantes por eso solo deja 0, declara masa como valor float PD(Declaras masa 2 veces, tanto en la función para realizar la operación, como en el privado de la clase, en la clase está como flotante y en el metodo cambia a entero)